# RouteName from Attribute based routing in Webapi2

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api2

I am using attribute based routing for my webapi2. I want to get the name of the route from the requested url in a delegating handler. Could you please help me out how can i get that?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a route like below in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
routes.MapRouteWithName(
    "RouteName",
    "{controller}/{action}/{username}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "List" }
    );
```

For above route you can use below in controller to get route value:

```
using System.Web.Routing

RouteData.DataTokens["RouteName"]
```

Comment: I am using attribute routing. I don't want to configure convention based routing.